# How to check the process loading sequence after Gnome Desktop starts

Tags: gnome, freeze, 23.10

Note that this is not related to the Boot process, for example using systemd-analyze blame or others.

This is related to, after the Gnome desktop starts, for me, it freezes for several seconds (Something like 20 to 30 seconds), and then I can use apps like files, open the terminal, etc.. But during that time frame no app will open nor can I click stuff.

Of course something is off but I need to be able to diagnose what it is, in a very similar fashion as checking the boot process with systemd. Basically, to see in the gnome environment, what loaded first, how much time it took from the "from loading to becoming interactive", so that I can see what is making gnome freeze for something like 20 to 30 seconds.

Currently, I checked the startup applications and there was nothing in there that was not there before when it worked properly.

what other suggestions could there be to check what is going on with gnome at this point.

Comment: Have you explored systemd-analyze only with the system instance, or have you also tried `systemd-analyze --user blame`?

Comment: @steeldriver correct but this only brings everything about the boot process, not after the boot process. .

Comment: Specifically the, let's call it, gnome boot process. Something weird ia happening after gnome starts. I currently have too many things on tje computer to actually start Ubuntu from scratch so I need a way to check the gnome startup process to see what oa happening. It actually started about a month ago with this issue. But now it is just ridiculous to see gnome desktop start, freeze for 20 to 30 seconds and then continue as nothing ever happened. Aome process or sub process freezes the whole gnome environment for that amount of time and tools to diagnose this where systemd does not.